# How to prevent redirection in a certain circumstance?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

At work we have an auth service that redirects you to the previously visited page which works perfectly.

But: if your jwt expires and you need to log back in, and do whatever you wanted to do. We have a `location.back()` after a successful save, however in this case it's returning you to the login page rather it should get you to a pre-edit page.

So when you follow the workflow it's working as intended but if you need to login again and save right after it get you back to login.

How can I programatically prevent this behavior?

I don't want to hardcode the routes.

If you need some snippets let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about saving the current URL when the user starts navigating to the edit page, and then navigating to that URL instead of using `location.back()` ?

Comment: I'd like to have a unified solution, since we are using this in more than 3-4 times application-wise i'd like to have a centralized option to deal with this issue.

Comment: @AlexBene and from that requirement, what prevents you from using the solution given by xdecdec ?